# Free Energy per Particle of an Ideal Gas in the Thermodynamical limit diverges to infinity

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I know that the Partition function of an ideal Gas is:

$$
Z_k = \frac{1}{N!} \left( \frac{V}{\lambda_T^3} \right) ^N
$$
where $\lambda_T = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2 \pi m k_B T}} $.

Now I want to calculate the free energy per particle in the Thermodynamical limit ($N \rightarrow \infty$). 
My approach is as following:

We know that:

$$
F = -k_B \ln(Z_k)
$$

Which means that for $N \rightarrow \infty$ we obtain:
$$
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}   \frac{F}{N} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} -\frac{k_B}{N} \ln\left( \left( \frac{V}{\lambda_T^3} \right)^N \frac{1}{N!} \right)
$$

which simplifies to:

$$
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}-\frac{k_B}{N} \left( N\ln\left(\frac{V}{\lambda_T^3}   \right) -\ln\left( N! \right) \right)
$$
and finally using Stirling's approximation:
$$
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}-k_B\left( \ln\left(\frac{V}{\lambda_T^3}   \right) -\ln\left( N \right) -1\right)
$$

However, this expression diverges to infinity because of the logarithm. Which should converge otherwise, we would have infinite energy.

Comment: Have you tried to take the limit $N \to \infty$ and $V\to \infty$ sucht that $n=N/V$ is constant?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker So basically it isnt reasonable to have infinite Particles in a finite Volume. With N/V = n then it converges. +1